# Koala facebook graph API query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

How do I construct a search with koala's syntax for users by their email, city, firstname and lastname.

The syntax documentation for graph API and koala are sparse, simplistic, or cover the url string syntax, and not the koala syntax.

Can someone please help? I've dug through both API for a while, and I'm hitting a wall. Thank you.

I have something like this so far

```
def facebook
  @koala = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.token) if user_signed_in?
  @people = Person.all
  @people.each do |p|
    result = @koala.get_object("people named \'#{p.personal_name} #{p.family_name}\' who live near #{p.city}")
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried FB console? `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2`

Comment: yes, but that is for url strings, whereas koala api methodsare different syntax from the fb url api. This is where documentation is lacking, even in the koala wiki and readme.